# QTextEdit и изображения

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Имеется ли способ "вытащить" изображения из QTextEdit() для дальнейшего верного сохранения .html файлов с указанием пути к изображениям в тэге ?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример того, что у вас есть.

Comment: @S.Nick Функция сохранения текстовика в формате .html. Используется метод toHtml() и последующая запись в файл. Думаю пример кода здесь не нужен.